# querying base and subtype with different include

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have a type and sub type

```
public class Reservation
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public TimeSpan Length {get; set;}
}
public class Appointment : Reservation
{
   public Customer Customer {get; set;}
}
```

DbContext

```
public DbSet<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
```

table per hierarchy (TPH) is the current setup since it's the only option for ef core 3.1.

Now I would like to query the superset `Reservations` and include the `Customer` when a `Reservation` is `Appointment`. I tried to use `union` on `IQueryable` like this

```
var reservations = context.Appointments.Include(e => e.Customer)
                   .Union(context.Reservations)
```

But I get

> InvalidOperationException: 'When performing a set operation, both
> operands must have the same Include operations

While it is possible to perform the `Union` in memory. I would like to perform one-trip-query that saves the day. I might migrate to `EntityFramework core 5` if a solution only exists there.

EDIT: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16298

Comment: What does your table(s) schema look like?  Inheritance and relational databases are often not a good match.

Comment: it's a single table (table per hierarchy)

Comment: @Flydog57 where did you get that from? Inheritance is used a lot, e.g. with microsoft identity etc. The EFCore team is even showing it in examples.

Comment: @MHDuke what do you expect the result to be. An `Iqueryable<Appointment>` with `Customer` null for the `Reservation` types? Or something else?

Comment: @JHBonarius no, I expect a set of the both types. Currently querying the base type alone Reservations, would result in a set of both types correctly casted. that said my experiment was not thorough. i have more info investigate and add to question. InvalidOperationException: 'Set operations over different entity types are currently unsupported (see #16298)' after I remove the Include()

Comment: I assume It will not work with EF Core 5 also. It is almost impossible to do eager loading  in this case.

Comment: ?? A set of both types? You do know C# is strongly typed, right? `var` is not some magic dynamic type.

Comment: I understand, i will use means of casting. ef core initializes the correct concrete type for each record in table via discriminator column/property. https://imgur.com/Z3xIfa3

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this approach, not sure it will work with EF Core, since it has problems with Concat/Union. Also your case needs `Concat` - `UNION ALL`, not `Union` - `UNION`.

```cs
var query1 = 
    context.Appointments.Select(e => new Appointment
    {
        Id = e.Id,
        Length = e.Length,
        Cutomer = e.Customer 
    });

 var query2 = 
    context.Reservations.Select(e => new Appointment
    {
        Id = e.Id,
        Length = e.Length,
     }); 

var query = query1.Concat(query2);
```

if you need concrete classes, you have to do transformation on the client side. Also in ChangeTracker will be recorder only Customers.

Comment: you suggest merging the results in runtime. which is feasible option and it's how i implemented it before asking the question. i prefer using context.Reservations.AsEnumerable().Union(context.Appointments.Include(e=> e.Customer).AsEnumerable()), because my classes has private constructors and no way to set the id manually. but this and your solution basically the same thing. However, context.Reservations.ToArray() will retrieve everything Reservations and Appointments, hence it's Union not Union All. the problem with the Include() statement.

Comment: AsEnumerable - is running query immediately, so this is not an option. I have proposed way which will load Customer, one-to-one relationship. One-to-many will not work at all.

Comment: Enumerable utilizes deferred execution strategy, so no, AsEnumerable(), does not execute query immediately, rather when we enumerate the results. on the other hand, Select() does indeed execute the query immediately.

Comment: You are right, but i mean that AsEnumerable forces to execute two queries.